# Proper way to remove a Trigger

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working with a form where some ComboBoxes can be created and removed programmatically.

When they are created, some triggers which target them are created and applied to a button:

```
    Dictionary<ComboBox, DataTrigger> triggers = new Dictionary<ComboBox, DataTrigger>();

    private void CreateTrigger(ComboBox box)
    {
        Style s = new Style(typeof(Button), MyButton.Style);
        foreach(TriggerBase aTrigger in MyButton.Style.Triggers)
            s.Triggers.Add(aTrigger);

        DataTrigger t = new DataTrigger 
          { 
            Binding = new Binding("SelectedItem") { Source = box }, 
            Value = null 
          };
        t.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.IsEnabledProperty, false));
        s.Triggers.Add(t);

        triggers.Add(box, t);

        MyButton.Style = s;
    }
```

So far so good*. . . the problem is, what to do when the ComboBox is removed from the window.  I need to remove the trigger from the button's Style, since I no longer want the ComboBox to influence its behavior.  I tried the most obvious option:

```
    private void RemoveTrigger(ComboBox box)
    {
        Style s = new Style(typeof(Button), MyButton.Style);
        foreach(TriggerBase aTrigger in MyButton.Style)
            if(aTrigger != triggers[box]) s.Triggers.Add(aTrigger);

        triggers.Remove(box);

        MyButton.Style = s;
    }
```

But this does not seem to do the job - if the trigger is removed while it is active, then the button stays disabled.

I had assumed that the button would re-evaluate its Style whenever it is given a new one.  that seems to be happening when the trigger is added, but not when it's being removed - what am I missing here?

**EDIT:**  Changed code for adding/removing triggers as per the advice in [H.B.'s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822141/proper-way-to-remove-a-trigger/6822501#6822501).  However, the problem in question remains.

**EDIT 2:** *Maybe not so far so good after all - I went on to try adding an additional ComboBox (and trigger) and discovered that adding a second trigger seems to break the first one.  Using this code, only the most recently added trigger works.  Should I be perhaps thinking of a FrameworkElement's triggers as a write-once collection and finding a different way to achieve this kind of behavior?

Comment: If the Button is removed, wouldn't the Trigger be removed at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a long time since this question was asked, but I figured I'd at least post how I resolved the issue for the sake of sharing:

I never did find a way to remove triggers that worked reliably.  So instead, I added a property to my View which indicated how all the triggers would have evaluated, if they had existed, and hooked a `DataTrigger` up to this property.

```
public bool TriggerPoseur { get; set; }  // Actually notifies when it changes
```

In place of adding and removing triggers, created an handlers to watch the properties that the triggers would have watched:

```
public void ComboBoxDataContext_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) { //update TriggerPoseur }
```

This sidesteps all the hassle with creating and removing triggers.  Instead there's one trigger, and adding and removing event handlers works just fine.

(Hacky, yes.)

Answer (score 1):

So you create a style `BasedOn` the style of `MyButton` (that is what this contructor does), then you add the trigger and change the reference of your button's style to your new style. In the removal you create a new style, again based on the style currently referenced by your button, remove a trigger from its trigger collection **which will not do anything as the collection is empty** and then reassign this style again.

Nope, this of course won't work.

**Edit:** Create a base-style as a readonly reference, then when those dynamic triggers are to be added or removed create a new style based on your reference and recreate all triggers while iterating over your trigger-collection.

Comment: Aha, I had missed that creating a style based on an existing one does not copy its Triggers collection.   However, the problem remains - the new Style still doesn't contain the trigger I want to remove, so why does the Trigger still seem to have an influence?

Comment: @SeanU: Indeed, i thought this might have been your assumption so just now i added an additional note while you commented.

Comment: Thanks, and I'm workign around that bit right now, but I was adding a question while you edited.  There must be some solution along these lines, since editing MyButton.Style directly is not permitted.

Comment: @SeanU: Create a base style as a readonly reference, then when triggers are to be added or removed create a new style based on that and recreate all triggers by iterating over your trigger-collection.

Comment: @HB: Just finished moving over to that, and am about to update my sample code to reflect it.  It doesn't work.  The button stays disabled.

Comment: @SeanU: This has to work, i made a simple test myself and it behaves as expected. I wonder what's off...

Comment: Could you post some sample code that I could compare against?

Comment: @SeanU: I am not doing any iteration (just one trigger vs. no trigger) but it should not make a difference i think (initialisations are ommitted): [<Snippet>](http://pastebin.com/H3Dj1ead)

Comment: I see code for adding a trigger in the snippet, but what about removing?  Adding works just fine for me, too.

Comment: @SeanU: The removing is just the creation of a new style (based on the `_baseStyle` without adding any triggers. In your case you remove the trigger from your collection, then create a new style and only add the triggers which are left in the collection.

Comment: @SeanU: I haven't created any iterating version but what i posted works, if the button is disabled and i replace the style with the trigger-less style the button becomes enabled again. (Did you include any of those dynamic triggers in the base-style? If so that should not be the case)

Comment: I haven't been working with a base style as you describe, as the button has some other triggers that are defined in XAML.  Instead I've just been trying to clone the button's current style, like in the current version of the sample code.  Is there a reason why there needs to be a separate object for the base style?